# Lmit the result returning from specific json parameter

Tags: mongodb

I  need to select the top 5 from specific parameter inside json object stored in mongo

eg:

```
 {
  students:[{
      id:number,
      name: string,
      count:number
 }],
  teachers:[{
      id:number,
      name: string,
      count: number
 }]
}
```

I need to return the top 5 of students and top 3 of teachers.

Here is my query, any suggestion for making this query work for me plz

```
 db.collection('people').find({
    ??????
}, {})
```

Edit: They already sorted by specific count, so all that I need to do is just to retrieve top 5 –

Comment: Which based you have to sort student? By I'd?

Comment: Good question, they already sorted by specific count, so all what I need to do is just to retrieve top 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use `$slice` for return specific number of `items` from an `array`.

Example :

```
db.getCollection('people').find( {}, { students: { $slice: 5}, teachers: { $slice: 3 } })
```

Note:

> Tested in mongo version `3.6.5` and Mongo GUI

Comment: It works when I add projection <code> db.getCollection('people').find( {}, {projection:{ students: { $slice: 5}, teachers: { $slice: 3 }} }) </code>